# Could not find 'ruby-debug-ide' in VS Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use VS Code for debugging a Ruby on Rails application. I have installed both the Ruby and Rubocop extension into VS Code. Then I have installed `ruby-debug-ide -v 0.6.0` and `debase -v 0.2.1` both via `sudo gem install` and `rvmsudo gem install`. However, when trying to debug the application using Rails server, I get the following exception:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs'
: 
Could not find 'ruby-debug-ide' (>= 0.a) among 48 total gem(s)
 (
Gem::LoadError
)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1:/home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/rdebug-ide:22:in `<main>'
```

However, when I list all installed gems with `rvm all do gem list`, neither of the installed gems are there:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

...
concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
...
rdoc (4.2.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
...
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: I've got this issue as well, were you able to find a solution in the end?

Comment: Actually, yes, I have just posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case, the solution was quite simple. As a newbie in Ruby on Rails, I did not realize that instead of installing gems into Ruby root, I should specify them in my Gemfile. So, inside Gemfile I put only:

```
group :development do
  gem 'ruby-debug-ide', '0.6.0'
  gem 'debase', '0.2.1'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

and this solved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

I also had this issue for a while, there doesn't seem to be a clear cut way of resolving this problem. All I had to do was run vs code through the terminal and I could debug my rails project, assuming you are using Linux. Just make sure you don't open vs code via a shortcut.